# How to use fread (or readfile) function (PHP) to get the output result of another PHP page?

Tags: php, readfile, fread

## **Summary**

I am trying to use `fread` (or `readfile`) function (PHP) to get the output result of another PHP page. For example, I want to read (or even download as another file to my PC) the output result of the page “add.php?a=1&b=4”. Below is the PHP codes.

## **Code**

**read.php**

```
<?php
$filename = "add.php?a=1&b=4";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
echo $contents;        //I hope it can output “5” (the output result of the page “add.php?a=1&b=4”)
fclose($handle);
?>
```

**add.php**

```
<?php
echo $_GET["a"]+$_GET["b"];
?>
```

Below is the example of the `readfile` function. I want to download the output result of the page “add.php?a=1&b=4” as the file "result.txt". But it doesn't work either.

**readfile.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=result.txt"); 
readfile("add.php?a=1&b=4");
?>
```

How can I modify it?

Comment: Call me crazy: but what is wrong with `include` or `require`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. But let me tell you again, I said I want “the output result” of the page, without using `include` and `require`.

Comment: Why? That is exactly what `include` and `require` is meant for

Comment: Because the situation doesn't allow me to use `include` and `require` to get the output result. (In addition, `include` and `require` cannot read the output result directly) Especially the “download (readfile function)” case. The only way I can do is to read the output directly.

Comment: You can also use `curl` which may provide a few more options if required.

Comment: A local file on the local file system does not have query parameters (`?...`). That's only useful in a URL in an HTTP request. So you'd need to make a separate HTTP request; which is total insanity in practice and you'd never write code like this to solve real problems. Really think twice whether you don't simply have the wrong approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the web output, you need to read it through the HTTP server.

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=result.txt");
 echo file_get_contents("http://yourserver.example.com/add.php?a=1&b=4");
```

Comment: But if I want to output as a file and save it to my PC, how can I do?

Comment: Thank you so much. You help me so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "[absolute url]/add.php?a=1&b=4";

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"result.txt\""); 

readfile($url);
```